# When is the rank of Jacobian constant?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-rank

Suppose I've got a function $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ which I know is bijective.

Considering $\mathcal{J}$, the Jacobian of $\ f$, I want to understand what can be said about the rank of $\mathcal{J}(\mathbf{x})$.

Let's say I evaluate $\mathcal{J}(\mathbf{0})$, and find that the rank of $\mathcal{J}(\mathbf{0})$ is $k$. Does this mean that the rank of $\mathcal{J}(\mathbf{x})$ is $k$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Is there a theorem regarding this?

EDIT: If this is not enough that $f$ is a bijection, what if $f$ is a homeomorphism? Or of class $C^{\infty}$?

Comment: the Jacobian doesn't even make sense for an arbitrary bijection. you must impose enough regularity -- $C^1$ would be customary -- for the total derivative to exist.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry I should have explicitly said this that the function is differentiable.

Comment: well it's pretty easy to cook up $C^1$ bijections where the rank vanishes at a particular point. for a $C^1$ diffeomorphism, however, the rank of the Jacobian is constant.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is a bijection, the Jacobian need not even exist.  Let $m=n$ and $f$ be a generic permutation of $\Bbb{R}^m$.  A random permutation is unlikely to be continuous anywhere, much less have derivatives.

(Bi-)Continuity (being homeomorphic) isn't sufficient to guarantee a derivative exists.  Consider continuous nowhere differentiable functions, for example, the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

A standard counterexample to $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}$ being sufficient is $f(x) = x^3$, which is rank deficient at $x=0$ and full rank everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not true. For example, consider $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^3$. Then $\mathcal{J}(x) = 3x^2$, so the rank of the Jacobian at $x = 0$ is zero, but $f$ has full rank at every other point.

Note, it follows from the [Inverse Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) that if $f$ has full rank at $x$, then it has full rank in a neighbourhood of $x$.